# Using Microsoft Account vs. Local one to back-up Bitlocker recovery key

Tags: c#, windows-10, microsoft-account, bitlocker

I am trying to encrypt my hard drive, on a Windows 10 Pro machine, with Bitlocker. I got to the point where I need to back-up my recovery key via a Microsoft Account, USB drive, or print it out. When I attempt to go the Microsoft Account route, it asks me for the credentials for my local offline account. I am reluctant to give it my credentials because I've heard the local account will then be converted to an online one, without my consent, which I don't want.

So my question is, can I back-up my Bitlocker recovery key on a Microsoft Account without my local account being stealthily converted to an online one? And if that does happen anyway, can i convert it back to being an offline one, while still keeping my Bitlocker recover key on my Microsoft Account?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to backup it on your Microsoft Account, just save it locally and upload it manually to your OneDrive account. Otherwise Microsoft will convert your local account to an online microsoft account.